# Converting a $6 \times 3$ generator matrix into a check matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

How would i go about converting a $6 \times 3$ matrix into a check matrix in the field $F_2$?

I have tried to convert the generator matrix into standard form $(I|P)$ and then convert it into a check matrix by using the formula $H=(P^T|I_{n-k})$

$P^T$ indicates the transpose of $P$ and $I_{n-k}$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix in this case.

This is the generator matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\  
  \end{bmatrix}

Comment: That would be [1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0;1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0;0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1] if I understood all the details correctly?

Comment: Mathjax turtorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. `$\begin{matrix}11&12&13 \\ 21&22&23 \\ 31&32&33 \\...\end{matrix}$` for matrices

Comment: @Shuri2060 thank you for the edit

Comment: @PaulStelian how did you arrive at that answer, can i convert it to a check matrix straight away or do i have to turn it into a  [3x6] matrix first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a quick tour on coding theory.

A [generator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_matrix) is a matrix whose rows form a basis for a linear code.

Let's inspect $2$nd, $4$th, and $6$th row of the generator matrix, they are $\begin{bmatrix}  1& 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}  0& 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}  0& 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$

Hence the codewords are every element of $F_2^3$.

A [check matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix) maps all codewords and only the codewords to the zero vector. To map every element of $F_2^3$ to the zero vector,  the corresponding parity check matrix has to be the zero matrix.

Edit:

As OP uses $6$-bit codeword, the convention is different. Hence one strategy would be take your matrix $G$ and take its transpose, $G^T$. Perform row operations to reduce it to its RREF form, that is in the form of $(I|P)$. After which, the parity check matrix is of the form of $(P^T|I)$

Comment: Would the check matrix just be a 3 × 6 zero matrix then? Also using the answer how would i find out whether a given 6 bit codeword is a valid codeword with respect to the check matrix?

Comment: As you mention that your codeword is $6$ bits, you are using a different convention from the wikipedia page. In that case, you can perform elementary operations to convert your generator matrix to a standard form before applying the transform.